# How do You Come Up With New Ideas for Open Source project?

Tags: open-source

You can see lots of briliant ideas in Open source projects. How authors found these ideas whey they don't exist yet?

Should I learn software dynamics, history and trends(Nothing new under the sun?) for that?
I don't want to start another github project called "API to xyz". What should I do??

Comment: This question would be better received at http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scratch an itch. Find something that you feel is a problem or annoying and write some code to solve that problem. Chances are you aren't the only person who is affected by that particular problem.

Comment: +1 for those magic three words.

Answer (score 2):

I believe a lot of software projects, open source or not, start as someone identifying a demand and working to supply it.

Think you're not satisfied with wherever photo management apps you found. Starting (or forking an existing one) with your needs in mind is an option.

What kind of software you would like to use but can find one that suits you? If yours needs are more or less supplied by already existing applications, why not working on improving one you like most?